# Who stands at the top of the mountain in The End (Fin)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-end

In [*The End* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2046090/), or *Fin* (original title), the main characters see a person standing at the top of a mountain. They shout and wave at the person, but the person doesn't react and leaves a few seconds later. We know it's not Angel, and there are apparently no other survivors, except for the girl near the end.

Who is that person?

Answer (score 0):

Just another human.  We know that Cova disappears long after the flash, and we know about the girl on the yacht and how she disappears in front of their eyes.  So, the person on the mountain was just another human who had not yet disappeared.  It was just showing that not everyone had disappeared yet.

Comment: And while this is almost certainly true, can you offer any evidence to back this up, or is it just your own personal opinion?

Comment: @Valorum - I can't find any evidence to support or dispute it.  But if that person was a character from the movie, I'd assume they'd make it more obvious or at least leave some clue.  That's why I think it was just a random person used to show that they're not alone.